# How i can parse in Json Object or Array? Where is error on my code?

Tags: android, json, parsing, jsonparser

I have some error parse Json on Android Studio,
Please if you have any idea can you share where is my error.

I want to get the current exchange rate information and print it on textview.

Json/Api Url : https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD

```
private void jsonParse() {
    
    String SHOP_URL = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=EUR,GBP";
     
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, SHOP_URL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("rates");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            int xGBP=result.getInt("GBP");
                                 
                            usdtry.setText(String.valueOf(xGBP));
                        }
                        
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    pRequestQueue.add(request);

}
```

This code not erroring but not response any..I think i have some missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rates` is a `JsonObject`, not an Array.

So, your code must be

```
JSONObject rates = response.getJSONObject("rates");
double xGBP = rates.getDouble("GBP");
usdtry.setText(String.valueOf(xGBP));
```

Also, for better formatting, you can use:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
usdtry.setText(formatter.format(xGBP));
```

Comment: Thanks i changed my code like your solution but still not show result on my textview.
Do I need to use the JsonObjectRequest part?

Comment: @LutfuA. You must be getting some error logs from the `e.printStackTrace();`s you have. Please post them in the question

Comment: Then you just have to debug it. Try to print the JSON response and the rates object

Comment: Where should I add the URL when using just the Jsonobject object?

Is response required?

Comment: Thank you for solution. i understood where is my error.